# Ubuntu hosting in Azure possible?

Tags: ubuntu, azure

I have got an Ubuntu image in Virtual Box working locally. The image boots automatically providing a user interface hosting several web apps.

Can this be hosted on an Azure instance ?

(ps: this image should be used for testing, not with a browser)

Comment: I've found it best to build images destined for Azure in Hyper-V. I can't say whether a VirtualBox image will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your image cannot be hosted on Azure directly. Because I assume that your image is not a cloud image and have not been prepared.

Azure supports [Official Ubuntu cloud images](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/). If you need to build your own specialized Ubuntu image for Azure, rather than use the manual procedure below it is recommended to start with these known working VHDs and customize as needed.

If you want to migrate your VM from on-premise Virtual Box to Azure, you need do more steps to achieve this.

First, I suggest you **convert your VM from Virtual Box to Hyper-V**.You could always run [**Disk2VHD**](https://docs.microsoft.com/zh-cn/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd) from within the OS of the VirtualBox VM and copy out the VHD to the physical machine.

Then, you need do some manual steps for your Ubuntu image. You can refer to [this official document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-upload-ubuntu#manual-steps) for more details.